# Substructural Prolog?

Tags: formal-languages, logic, prolog

Substructural logic is logic without some or all of the structural rules. Is substructural Prolog, substructural logic programming possible? My question is connected with article https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-40030-3_8 *Grammar Induction as Substructural Inductive Logic Programming* - if substructural Prolog is possible then one can implement substructural inductive logic programming in it (e.g. http://ilasp.com/ for the answer set version of ILP over Prolog in the non-substructural setting) and apply, e.g. in grammar induction case.

How hard the usual (e.g. SWI) Prolog should be remade to be used as substructural Prolog?

Comment: http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~dale/lolli/

Comment: @DanDoel: do you know of an ordered one, like what Jeff Polakow did in his thesis? Surely someone at CMU must have implemented something.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of anything like that, but I'm far from an expert in this area.

Answer (score 4):

Logic programming with substructural logics has been studied, starting in the second half of the 90's. I am not an expert, but I can probably provide enough references to get you going.

There is Dale Miller's [Lolli](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~dale/lolli/), a programming language for linear logic programming.

Major research was carried out by [Frank Pfenning](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/) and his coworkers and students. For example:

- Frank Pfenning: lecture notes on [Linear logic programming](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/linear/handouts/lp.pdf), part of a course on [linear logic](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/linear/) (the web site also has some software)
- Iliano Cervesato, Frank Pfenning: [A Linear Logical Framework](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/papers/lics96.pdf)
- Jeff Polakow, Frank Pfenning: [Properties of Terms in Continuation-Passing Style in an Ordered Logical Framework](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/papers/lfm00.pdf)
- Frank Pfenning, Robert J. Simmons: [Substructural Operational Semantics as Ordered Logic Programming](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/papers/lics09.pdf)

I am pretty sure someone implemented logic programming for ordered linear logic, poke around the work done by Jeff Polakow and Frank Pfenning. I don't seem to be able to find it right now.